# How should I display my plot on basemap properly?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have plotted my coordinates and output is like this. but I would like to display these plots on basemap but I don't know how I can do this. I have seen some codes on the web but when I use them output isn't what I want.
I've used these codes to plot my coordinates:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
for evento, group in Final_data.groupby(['MMSI']):
    x = group.X.values
    y = group.Y.values
    plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=1.5 ,)
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
```

[the outout of my plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vbIq.jpg)

I've used this code to display basemap under my plots:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
m = Basemap(projection='lcc', resolution=None,
width=8E6, height=8E6,
lat_0=25, lon_0=-100)
m.etopo(scale=0.5, alpha=5)
m.plot(Final_data.X,Final_data.Y,color='red')
```

[plots on basemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIL7f.jpg)

as you can see my plots on basemap isn't illustrative.
what I can do to display plots on basemap properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need proper coordinate conversion in this statement of your code:

```
m.plot(Final_data.X, Final_data.Y,color='red')
```

Since I have no clue on the data, Let me put up a point coordinate (Gulf  of Mexico) to transforn and plot.

```
lat1,lon1 = [25.505915, -93.709812]
```

The proper code that transforms the coordinates (long,lat) degrees to projection coordinates in meters, then plots the location:

```
m.plot( *m(lon1,lat1), color='red')
```

Comment: My coordinates are in meters and I don't think need to convert them again

Comment: @Danial To get correct plot, coordinate system, correct sequence (x,y) or (long,lat), ... are required.

Comment: My coordinates were lat, lon but I changed them into X, Y with Wgs84_UTM and as you can see I've plotted X, Y and the sequence (X, Y) is correct. I don't understand what you mean exactly

Comment: @Danial Based on `m = Basemap(projection='lcc', ...)`, you are plotting data in `lcc` projection. A projection is a coordinate system. You must convert your data to that system to plot correctly.